# Adding p-values to ggplot but removing the line

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I want to add the p-value to the plot but hide the not significant values. If I use label="p.signif", I am able to do that but the line still remains. Also all *** stars are shown.

If I use the "p.format", all p-values are shown even the non significant values.
Anyone can please help.

Thanks

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggpubr)
p1<-ggplot(df1,aes(x = Group,y = NMNAT1,fill = Group)) +
  geom_boxplot( palette = c("#E7B800", "#FC4E07", "#00AFBB")) + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.2)) + labs(title= "NMNAT1") +
  xlab("Group") + ylab("NMNAT1") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 
p1

p1+ stat_compare_means(
  method = "t.test",
  label="p.signif",
  tip.length = 0.01,
  sysnum.args=list(cutpoints=c(0.05,1)),
  symbols=c("*","ns"),
  hide.ns = TRUE,
  comparisons = my_comparisons, 
  )
```

Comment: what library has `stat_compare_means()` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is [not currently possible](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/60) to automatically hide non-signficiant comparisons with `stat_compare_means`:

Instead, manually select the significant comparisons with `comparisons =` .

Also note that you have a number of other mistakes in your code which I have cleaned up. `symnum.args =` requires a named list of arguments. `cutpoints =`  must be one element longer than `symbols =` .

```
library(ggplot2);library(ggpubr)
ggplot(df1,aes(x = Group,y = NMNAT1,fill = Group)) +
  geom_boxplot() + scale_color_manual(values = c("#E7B800", "#FC4E07", "#00AFBB")) + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.2)) + labs(title= "NMNAT1") +
  xlab("Group") + ylab("NMNAT1") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", label="p.signif", tip.length = 0.01,
                     symnum.args=list(cutpoints=c(0,0.05,1), symbols=c("*","ns")),
                     comparisons = list(c(1,2),c(2,3)))
```

[image: Graph]

Data:

```
setseed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("Control","Mild","Severe"),each = 100), NMNAT1 = unlist(lapply(c(4,3,3.75),function(x)rnorm(100,mean = x, sd = 0.75))))
```